# What does HTTP 400 when pulling docker image mean?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, ubuntu-server

I am asking docker to build an ASP.NET 5 beta6 application image for me at Ubuntu 14.04.1 virtual machine:

```
docker build -t instanceName .
```

using dockerfile that starts with:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta6
```

It responds with this message:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 124.4 kB
Sending build context to Docker daemon
Step 0 : FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta6
Pulling repository microsoft/aspnet
9424b500cebc: Error pulling image (1.0.0-beta6) from microsoft/aspnet, HTTP code 400
ba249489d0b6: Download complete
19de96c112fc: Download complete
b92a854a78d0: Download complete
63e9265ef57c: Error pulling dependent layers
INFO[0019] Error pulling image (1.0.0-beta6) from microsoft/aspnet, HTTP code 400
```

It does similar thing when I replace dockerfile definition to just `FROM microsoft/aspnet`.

What does it mean? If it were 404, I would understand that there is no such image. But "Bad Request"? Can I make the request... better?

Comment: according to https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnet/, 1.0.0-beta1 to 1.0.0-beta7 should be correct, can you check what happens when you put either 1 or 4 or 7 at the end?

Comment: this Dockerfile looks correct https://hub.docker.com/r/akoeplinger/mono-aspnetvnext/~/dockerfile/ and is not much different from yours

Comment: ``Error pulling image (1.0.0-beta1) from microsoft/aspnet, HTTP code 400``, ``Error pulling image (1.0.0-beta4) from microsoft/aspnet, HTTP code 400``, ``Error pulling image (1.0.0-beta7) from microsoft/aspnet, HTTP code 400``

Comment: It's interesting that ``akoeplinger/mono-aspnetvnext`` works from my VM! Unfortunatelly, it's refering to too old version, so I can't actually use it, but it's dependending on ``microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta1``, isn't it? I don't understand it.